# Can a Java application deployed to Tomcat/WildFly be patched?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, wildfly

My area of expertise is not in Java; I write Java code snippets where needed by my other apps. Others in my organization do work with Java.

For a large browser-based app developed in Java using Eclipse Oxygen and deployed on Tomcat or WildFly on a RedHat 7 server, how does one create a patch? i.e. where a couple of JSP's and classes have changed, must the complete WAR be created and redeployed? Or, is there a way to generate a WAR that only has these changes, and deploy it on target machine via CLI or TC/WF console?

The complete WAR may be a few gigs in size so would take longer to email to client, whereas a 50KB patch would appeal more to a sense of neatness. Also, if I send out monthly updates with full WAR's, the backup size would be much larger.

Is there a tutorial one could follow?

Comment: Tomcat can work will exploded war directory, if you have small change, you can stop the server and put the relevant jar file in that exploded war directory and start the server. You cannot simply put a patch while running the application. However this patching concept can be applied in case OSGI model running in Glassfish server.

Comment: On WildFly you have several solutions:
 * deployment-overlays which allow you to overlay files from a deployment: https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Admin_Guide.html#Deployment_Overlays
 * exploded deployments which allow you to replace files: https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Admin_Guide.html#exploded-managed-deployments

Comment: Thanks, I'll check into what deployment overlays are and how they work.

Comment: What about sending the client a patch which is the new files/classes and a script that basically does a `zip -u app.war [files...]`?